# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PoolManager'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

print drive.title
```

I have tried using Firefox and Chrome webdriver, but I'm getting same error as below for both of them.

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PoolManager'

```
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.14.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 169, in __init__
    remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.14.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\remote_connection.py", line 23, in __init__
    RemoteConnection.__init__(self, remote_server_addr, keep_alive)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.14.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._conn = urllib3.PoolManager(timeout=self._timeout)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PoolManager'
```

Any  help will be appreciated

TIA

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: @mgracer updated the question